# Algorithm uniform distribution of elements in the matrix

Tags: c#, algorithm

I need to generate tasks in the month of the date of the random uniform distribution. For example, for 10 people to 10 tasks so that the dates are spaced not less than two days. Weekends and holidays are not to be used. Essentially uniform random distribution of elements in the multiplicity with the additional condition where the multiplicity - people x dates of month. Suggest, where I can watch the algorithm.

Comment: @ChaitanyaGadkari Thank you, I had already resolved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

In general decided somehow. However, I must say, a decision I do not like, but nothing better could not think. Parameters are as follows: tasksPerMonth - the number of jobs per month, distanceBetweenTasks - the minimum distance between two adjacent jobs, isTasksInWeekend - take into account whether or not the weekend, minDay - starting from this day (for various reasons, this may not be the first day of the month), listOfDays - initially empty, holidays - a list of days off and holidays, workdaysInMonth - list of working days, random - empty Random (). The rest, I think, in principle, it is clear, the function code is shown below OptimizationTheDistributionOfTasks

```
      public void GenerateRandomTasks(int tasksPerMonth, int distanceBetweenTasks, bool isTasksInWeekend, int minDay, List<int> listOfDays, List<int> holidays, List<int> workdaysInMonth, Random random)
{
    if (tasksPerMonth == 0)
        tasksPerMonth = 1;
    var daysInMonth = workdaysInMonth.Count + holidays.Count;
    var tasksDaysInMonth = !isTasksInWeekend ? workdaysInMonth.Count : daysInMonth;
    for (int i = 0; i < tasksPerMonth; i++)
    {
        int maxDayInPeriod;
        if (i < tasksPerMonth - 1)
        {
            maxDayInPeriod = minDay + tasksDaysInMonth / tasksPerMonth;
            if (!isTasksInWeekend && holidays.Contains(maxDayInPeriod))
                maxDayInPeriod = workdaysInMonth.First(v => v > maxDayInPeriod);
        }
        else
        {
            maxDayInPeriod = daysInMonth;
            if (!isTasksInWeekend && holidays.Contains(maxDayInPeriod))
                maxDayInPeriod = workdaysInMonth.Last();
        }

        if (minDay > maxDayInPeriod)
            minDay = maxDayInPeriod;

        var day = random.Next(minDay, maxDayInPeriod);

        if ((isTasksInWeekend != true && holidays.Contains(day)))
            day = OptimizationTheDistributionOfTasks(minDay, maxDayInPeriod, listOfDays, day, holidays);

        if (day > daysInMonth)
            day = daysInMonth;

        listOfDays.Add(day);
        minDay = maxDayInPeriod;
        if (minDay <= day + distanceBetweenTasks)
            minDay = day + distanceBetweenTasks + 1;
    }
}
```

Method OptimizationTheDistributionOfTasks:

```
       private int OptimizationTheDistributionOfTasks(int minDay, int maxDay, List<int> listDays, int day, List<int> holidays)
{
    var listOfDays = new List<DaysForTaskPlan>();
    for (int k = minDay; k <= maxDay; k++)
    {
        var tempCountDays = listDays.Count(d => k == d);
        if (!holidays.Contains(k))
            listOfDays.Add(new DaysForTaskPlan(k, tempCountDays));
    }
    if (listOfDays.Any())
    {
        day = listOfDays.First(p => p.AmountDays == listOfDays.Min(z => z.AmountDays)).CurrDay;
    }
    listOfDays.Clear();
    return day;
}
```

Good luck to all